# How to install paramiko in win7 and python34?

Tags: python-3.x

My system:win7+python3.4 .
I have installed Crypto and Paramiko .

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip3.4  install  Crypto
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Crypto in d:\python34\
```

lib\site-packages
    Cleaning up...

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip3.4  install  Paramiko
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Paramiko in d:\python3
```

4\lib\site-packages
    Cleaning up...

when import paramiko :

```
>>> import paramiko  
  Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
  File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\paramiko\__init__.py", line 30, in <module
  from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport   
  File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 49, in <module>      
 from paramiko.dsskey import DSSKey   
 File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\paramiko\dsskey.py", line 26, in <module>  
 from Crypto.PublicKey import DSA    
 ImportError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

When i change the F:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\crypto  into F:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\Crypto ,

```
import paramiko
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:\Python34\lib\site-packages\paramiko-1.13.0-py3.4.egg\paramiko\__in
```

_.py", line 31, in 
      File "F:\Python34\lib\site-packages\paramiko-1.13.0-py3.4.egg\paramiko\tran
rt.py", line 30, in 
      File "F:\Python34\lib\site-packages\paramiko-1.13.0-py3.4.egg\paramiko\util
", line 34, in 
      File "F:\Python34\lib\site-packages\paramiko-1.13.0-py3.4.egg\paramiko\comm
py", line 129, in 
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Random'

How can i solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've installed the wrong crypto module for Paramiko. The doc page says it requires [PyCrypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto) not [Crypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/crypto/). Uninstall Crypto and then `pip3.4 install pycrypto`.